# Adding a wpml link in wp_nav_menu with wrap

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a WPML language link in a wp_nav_menu with the code below. Unfortunately this doesn't work, the function other_language(); that outputs a language url is being displayed above the < ul > and not within his < li > . How can I solve this

```html
function my_nav_wrap() {
    $wrap  = '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">';
    $wrap .= '%3$s';
    $wrap .= '<li>';
    $wrap .= other_language();
    $wrap .= '</li>';
    $wrap .= '</ul>';

  return $wrap;
}

function other_language(){
    $languages = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0&orderby=code');
    if(!empty($languages)){
        foreach($languages as $l){
            if(!$l['active']){
                echo '<a href="'.$l['url'].'"class="lang-button">';
                echo $l['native_name'];
                echo '</a>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```